# What is laravel 5 validation library using?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, slim

As the title, I just wonder which validation library Laravel 5 is using and is there anyway that I can apply to my Slim project (from composer for ex.).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [illuminate/validation](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/validation). You can get it with `composer` in this way:

```
composer require illuminate/validation
```

Comment: Thank you so much!